# Why are some characters like "○" overlapped?

Tags: string, unicode, skype

I stumbled upon an interesting character while skyping. I was initially interested to send an empty message but, since Skype has some validation rules, it doesn't allow empty messages.

But, with a few `ALT+NUMPAD` ASCII symbols I saw that for `alt+777` it returns `○` on most editors and  `̉`  on skype, which delivers an empty-like message and this is where curiosity got to me. I started to abuse this symbol and noticed that it can overlap other characters. So if I write the ASCII symbol on a word, the result would be a ̉`mủt̉ả̉̉̉t̉ẻd̉W̉ỏ̉r̉̉d̉̉`.

You can see for yourself that `"̉mủt̉ả̉̉̉t̉ẻd̉W̉ỏ̉r̉̉d̉̉".length == 24` while `"mutatedWord".length == 11`.

And the funny thing is that, up until now, I could only generate that weird aphostrophy on skype, anywhere else it results in `○`.

Can someone explain this behavior to me?

Comment: Interesting question, but it should be moved to [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're writing Unicode codepoint 777 (but usually notated in hex as U+0307). This codepoint is one of Unicode's [combinbing characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character), namely "combining hook above". You've already discovered what they do: they add a diacritic to the next character.

If there's no letter following, there's no consisitent behavior. If Skype renders it differently from the other apps you've tried, it probably is using a different font engine.

Comment: You answer my question - indeed. But still - html browsers poorly handle this. Just watch :)
ả̉̉̉̉̉̉̉̉̉̉
And even OS, allowing so many duplicates of the same character.
I've yet to find some kind of major bugs (like a website demanding at least 6 characters in a username but me typing a letter and 5 diacritics on top of that letter.)
Anyway, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: My arithmetic says that decimal `777` = hexadecimal `0x309` (and not `0x307`).